# Variable in Color Code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'm trying to create a circle that iterates over all hues like so. Right is what I currently have.

[image]
[image]

```latex
\foreach\x in {5, 10, ..., 360} {
    \pgfmathparse{\x}
    \definecolor{tmpcolor}{HSB}{\pgfmathresult,255,255}
    \fill[color=tmpcolor](
        {0.5\textwidth + 0.22\textheight*sin(\x)},
        {-0.309017\textheight -0.22\textheight*cos(\x) + 0.5em}
    ) circle [radius = 1em];
}
```

How do I use the variable from `\foreach` in the color code, within the `tikz` environment.

Comment: Can you please make the example into a minimal compilable document? If I add it, I get “unsupported color model hsb”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hsb/Hsb colours in tikz if you load `xcolor` with the `rgb` option to set the target colour model to rgb:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x in {5, 10, ..., 360} {
    \definecolor{tmpcolor}{Hsb}{\x,1,1}
    \fill[color=tmpcolor](\x:22em) circle [radius = 1em];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to `xcolor`, to draw color wheel, color model `Hsb` (value space `[0, 360] * [0, 1] * [0, 1] \subset R^2`) is easier to use than `HSB` model (value space `[0, 240]^3 \subset Z^3`).

```tex
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawHsbColorWheel}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90, baseline=0pt]
    \foreach\x in {0, #1, ..., 360} {
        % define color in Hsb model which has space [0, 360] * [0, 1] * [0, 1]
        \definecolor{tmpcolor}{Hsb}{\x,1,1}
        % convert to rgb, since tikz doesn't support Hsb/hsb color model
        \colorlet{tmpcolor}[rgb]{tmpcolor}
        % draw colored dots on a 5cm-radius circle
        \fill[fill=tmpcolor] (\x:5cm) circle[radius={5cm/2*tan(#1)}];
        % add note at origin
        \node[font=\Huge] {Step = $#1^\circ$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\drawHsbColorWheel{10}

\drawHsbColorWheel{8}

\drawHsbColorWheel{5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks smaller and cleaner, but I keep getting errors (not sure why).
I firstly decided to work on 36 circles into three parts that need to change hue based on position. So, from another project of mine, I repurposed some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Iterate over a predefined list of hue values from 0 to 350 in steps of 10
    \foreach \hue [evaluate=\hue as \adjustedhue using {ifthenelse(\hue < 180, \hue + 120, \hue - 240)}] in {0,10,...,350} {
        % Calculate the red component based on the adjusted hue value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\red}{ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 60 || \adjustedhue >= 300, 1,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 180, 1 - (\adjustedhue - 60)/120,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 240, 0,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 300, (\adjustedhue - 240)/60, 1))))}
        % Calculate the green component based on the adjusted hue value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\green}{ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 60, \adjustedhue/60,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 180, 1,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 240, 1 - (\adjustedhue - 120)/120,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 360, 0, 1))))}
        % Calculate the blue component based on the adjusted hue value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\blue}{ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 180, 0,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 240, (\adjustedhue - 180)/60,
                    ifthenelse(\adjustedhue < 360, 1, 0)))}
        % Define the color using the RGB values
        \definecolor{tmpcolor}{rgb}{\red,\green,\blue}
        % Fill a circle at the corresponding position with the defined color
        \fill[color=tmpcolor] ({0.5\textwidth + 4cm*cos(\hue)}, {0.5\textwidth + 4cm*sin(\hue)}) circle [radius=1em];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates an output that looks like this:

[image: Test]

I hope this is somewhat helpful.